# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow Manager site stopped

Tags: workflow, iis7, manager

I have a SharePoint 2013 server farm with a web server (lets say SERVER-web) and an app server (let's say SERVER-app). The Workflow Management Site is installed on both, under IIS. They each have an https and http binding, and each have IP Address and Domains set to allow access to local and to each other.

Is it normal that the site is in Stopped on my app server?? I ask because I am running into an error when I open the UI page to view Workflows (Items > Workflows). The correlation ID tells me it's a problem with an IP address not permitted to access the site. However nothing has changed in that regard. In troubleshooting I noticed that the one Workflow Management Site is stopped but don't want to simply start it without fully understanding it.

Comment: did you follow the instructions to set up workflow? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx#section3

Comment: did you install the workflow Manager on both Server and both Server are part of single WFmanager farm?

Comment: I did not perform this installation. I inherited it. Both servers are part of a single farm and the Workflow manager and Workflow site in IIS are installed on both servers.

Comment: run get-wffarm in the workflow pwoershell

Comment: But anywho Workflow site should be started

Comment: I ran get-wffarm and see that under hosts it lists both servers. So you're pretty confident I can just start the site on the one that's off and should not have any issues?